# Test function with bounded gradient

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

How to construct a test function (radial) which is zero outside a ball of radius $2r$ and $1$ on the ball of radius $r$ but the gradient is bounded by $\dfrac{1}{r}$?

Comment: might it be that you want to bound it by $\frac{c}{r}$ for some positive $c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Take $r =1$ and let's work on the real line. Suppose there were such a function $f.$ Then $f(x) = 1, 0\le x \le 1,$ $f(x) = 0, x\ge 2,$ and $|f'(x)|\le 1$  everywhere. Note that $f'(1) = 0.$

Let $g(x)$ be the line connecting $(1,1)$ with $(2,0).$ Then the slope of $g$ is $-1.$ Because $f'(1) = 0,$ $f$ is above $g$ on $(1,1+\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon>0.$ The slope of the line connecting $(1+\epsilon,f(1+\epsilon))$ and $(2,0)= (2,f(2))$ is thus less than $-1.$ By the mean value theorem, this slope equals $f'(c)$ for some $c, 1+\epsilon<c<2.$ That is a contradiction, and therefore such an $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation. Much appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Now see that little check-mark icon? You can check that if you feel my answer deserves it.